# Completion Handler in Swift

Tags: ios, mkmapview, swift, mapkit, routes

I have been searching for many hours trying to find the solution to this closure problem in swift. I have found many resources for explaining the closures but for some reason I can't seem to get this working.

This is the Objective-C code I am trying to convert into swift:

```
[direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[response description]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);

            }];
```

and the swift I am trying but is not working:

```
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler(response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) {
    println(response.description)
    println(error.description)
}
```

directions is an `MKDirections` object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({
(response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) in 
        println(response?.description)
        println(error?.description)
    })
```

Comment: This worked thanks so much! God.. Closures.. XD I'll mark as answer when it lets me. Thanks again!

Comment: or short: `directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({(response, error) in /* code */ })`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is the general way a block/closure looks like in Swift.

if you don't need to use the parameters you can do it like this

```
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({
(_) in 
  // your code here
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding the syntax of [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html) in *Swift*, and checking the [`MKDirections`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/index.html) Class Reference:

[image]

it looks the proper closure here should be an [`MKDirectionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKDirectionsHandler), which defined as:

[image]

therefore the *completion handler* should look like this:

```
direction.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler( { (response: MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError!) -> () in
    println(response.description)
    println(error.description)
    } )
```

Comment: This post was tagged low quality. Despite your reputation, please add more explanations.

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy, my bad, sorry.